# Having errors when calling repository methods in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, jdbc

I am getting this error when calling repository methods at the bottom of the method. When those repository methods moved to top of the method they work.

These are the errors I am getting,

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
```

Below is the method which calls repository methods,

```java
    public ContractTabBean loadRoomCombinationInfo(Long hotelId) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("############################## loadRoomCombinationInfo : hotelId :" + hotelId);
    
            ContractTabBean contractTabBean = new ContractTabBean();
            try {
                System.out.println("ContractTabBean loadRoomCombinationInfo process start :::::::::: ");
                List<RoomtypeBean> roomTypeBeanList = contractTabBean.getRoomTypeBeanList();
                List<BedtypeBean> bedTypeBeanList = contractTabBean.getBedtypeBeanList();
                List<MealPlanBean> mealPlanBeanList = contractTabBean.getMealplanBeanList();
                contractTabBean.setHotelId(hotelId);
    
    
                List<Room> roomList = (List<Room>)this.roomRepository.findAll(); //2024-01-05
                System.out.println("####334 roomRepository.findByHotelId ==========" + roomList.size()); //2024-01-05
                // geting uniq list..
                List<String> roomtype = this.roomTypeRepository.roomTypeAsc();
                System.out.println("#### this.roomTypeRepository.roomTypeAsc() ==========" + roomtype.size());
                List<Roomtype> roomTypeList = new ArrayList<Roomtype>(0);
                if (Validator.validateListFirstObject(roomtype)) {
                    System.out.println("#### validateListFirstObject roomTypeList.size() ==========" + roomTypeList.size());
                    for (String roomtypestring : roomtype) {
                        System.out.println("#### roomtypestring ====" + roomtypestring);
                        Roomtype roomtypeobj = this.roomTypeRepository.findByRoomtypeAndHotelId(roomtypestring, hotelId);//error point
                        System.out.println("#### this.roomTypeRepository.findByRoomtypeAndHotelId ==========" + roomtypeobj);
                        if (Validator.validateObject(roomtypeobj)) {
                            roomTypeList.add(roomtypeobj);
                            System.out.println("#### validateObject - if ####");
                        } else {
                            List<Roomtype> roomtypeobj_ = this.roomTypeRepository.findByRoomtype(roomtypestring);
                            roomTypeList.add(roomtypeobj_.get(0));
                            System.out.println("#### validateObject - else ####");
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                // Get All room types and set checked as false
                // List<Roomtype> roomTypeList =
                // this.roomTypeRepository.findByOrderByRoomtypeAsc();
                roomTypeList.stream().forEach(roomType -> {
                    // roomTypeBeanList.add(new RoomtypeBean(roomType.getId(),
                    // roomType.getRoomtype(), false, hotelId));
                    RoomtypeBean roomTypeBean = new RoomtypeBean();
                    roomTypeBean.fillBeanFromEntity(roomType);
                    roomTypeBean.setChecked(false);
                    roomTypeBean.setHotelId(roomType.getHotel().getId());
                    roomTypeBeanList.add(roomTypeBean);
                    System.out.println("#### roomTypeList.stream().forEach(roomType -> { ####");
                });
    
                /*
                 * old logic before new requirement bedtype 17 july 2017 //geting uniq list..
                 * List<String> bedtype = this.bedTypeRepository.bedtypeAsc();
                 *
                 * List<Bedtype> bedTypeList = new ArrayList<Bedtype>(0);
                 * if(Validator.validateListFirstObject(bedtype)){ for (String bedtypestring :
                 * bedtype) { Bedtype bedtypeobj =
                 * this.bedTypeRepository.findByBedtypeAndHotelId(bedtypestring, hotelId);
                 * if(Validator.validateObject(bedtypeobj)){ bedTypeList.add(bedtypeobj); }else{
                 * List<Bedtype> bedtypeobj_ =
                 * this.bedTypeRepository.findByBedtype(bedtypestring);
                 * bedTypeList.add(bedtypeobj_.get(0)); } } }
                 */
    
                // geting uniq list..
                List<Bedtype> bedtype = this.bedTypeRepository.getAllbedtype();
                System.out.println("%%%%%%%% this.bedTypeRepository.getAllbedtype() ==========" + bedtype.size());
                System.out.println("%%%%%%%% bedtype.get(0)); ==========" + bedtype.get(0));
                System.out.println("%%%%%%%% bedtype obj ==========" + bedtype.get(0).getBedtype() + " | " +bedtype.get(0).getBedtype());
    
                List<Bedtype> bedTypeList = new ArrayList<Bedtype>(0);
                if (Validator.validateListFirstObject(bedtype)) {
                    for (Bedtype bedtypeDb : bedtype) {
                        Bedtype bedtypeobj = new Bedtype();
                        try {
                            if (null != bedtypeDb.getBedtype() || !bedtypeDb.getBedtype().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                                if (null != hotelId) {
                                    System.out.println("%%%%%%%% not null bedtype ----------> " + hotelId + "| " + bedtypeDb.getBedtype());
                                    bedtypeobj = this.bedTypeRepository.findByBedtypeAndHotelId(bedtypeDb.getBedtype(), hotelId);
                                }
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("######## null bedtype ----------> " + hotelId + "| " + bedtypeDb.getBedtype());
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            System.out.println("Exce : "+ e);
                        }
                        System.out.println(">>>>>>>> 2 bedtypeobj getBedtype : " + bedtypeobj);
                        if (Validator.validateObject(bedtypeobj)) {
                            System.out.println("#### BT ==========" + bedtypeobj.getBedtype());
                            if (!bedTypeList.contains(new Bedtype(bedtypeDb.getBedtype()))) {
                                bedTypeList.add(bedtypeobj);
                                System.out.println("#### 1 BT size==========" + bedTypeList.size());
                            }
                        } else {
                            /*--2024-01-04
                            List<Bedtype> bedtypeobj_ = this.bedTypeRepository.findByBedtype(bedtypeDb.getBedtype());
                            System.out.println("####2 BT.findByBedtype ==========" + bedtypeobj_.size());
                            if (Validator.validateList(bedtypeobj_)) {
                                System.out.println("#### 2 BT ==========" + bedtypeobj_.size());
                                if (!bedTypeList.contains(new Bedtype(bedtypeobj_.get(0).getBedtype()))) {
                                    bedTypeList.add(bedtypeobj_.get(0));
                                    System.out.println("#### 2 BT size==========" + bedTypeList.size());
                                }
                            }*/
                        }
                        System.out.println("****** BT size==========" + bedTypeList.size());
                    }
                    System.out.println("****** 2 BT size==========" + bedTypeList.size());
                }
                System.out.println("****** 3 BT size==========" + bedTypeList.size());
                //2024-01-04 Collections.sort(bedTypeList);
                System.out.println("#### 3 BT size==========" + bedTypeList.size());
                // Get All Bed types and set checked as false
                // List<Bedtype> bedTypeList = this.bedTypeRepository.findByOrderByBedtypeAsc();
                bedTypeList.stream().forEach(bedType -> {
                    // bedTypeBeanList.add(new BedtypeBean(bedType.getId(),
                    // bedType.getBedtype(), hotelId));
                    BedtypeBean bedtypeBean = new BedtypeBean();
                    bedtypeBean.fillBeanFromEntity(bedType);
                    System.out.println("---------BED type "+bedType.getBedtype()+" ");
                    if(bedType!=null && bedType.getBedtype()!=null && bedType.getHotel()!=null){
                        bedtypeBean.setHotelId(bedType.getHotel().getId());
                        bedTypeBeanList.add(bedtypeBean);
                    }
    
                    System.out.println("####bedTypeBeanList size ==========" + bedTypeBeanList.size());
                });
    
                // Get All meal Plan and set checked as false
                // List<Mealplan> mealPlanList = mealplanRepository.findByOrderByMealplanplanAsc();
                List<Mealplan> mealPlanList = /* mealplanRepository.findByMealPlanCode()*/new ArrayList<>();
                System.out.println("####3 mealplanRepository.findByOrderByMealplanplanAsc() ==========" + mealPlanList.size());
                /*mealPlanList.stream().forEach(mealPlan -> {
                    // mealPlanBeanList
                    // .add(new MealPlanBean(mealPlan.getId(),
                    // mealPlan.getMealplanplan(), mealPlan.getMealplancode()));
                    MealPlanBean meanPlanBean = new MealPlanBean();
                    meanPlanBean.fillBeanFromEntity(mealPlan);
                    mealPlanBeanList.add(meanPlanBean);
                });*/
    
                // Iterate all roomlist and checked if given hotel has any room then set
                // it as checked
                System.out.println("this.roomRepository.findByHotelId(hotelId) hotelId"+hotelId);
                /* List<Room> roomList = (List<Room>)this.roomRepository.findAll();
                System.out.println("####334 roomRepository.findByHotelId ==========" + roomList.size()); 2024-01-05*/
                roomList.stream().forEach(room -> {
                    RoomtypeBean roomTypeBean = new RoomtypeBean(room.getRoomtype().getId(), room.getRoomtype().getRoomtype());
                    int index = roomTypeBeanList.indexOf(roomTypeBean);
                    if (index != -1) {
                        RoomtypeBean getRoomTypeBean = roomTypeBeanList.get(index);
                        getRoomTypeBean.setChecked(true);
                        getRoomTypeBean.setRoomBeanId(room.getId());
                        getRoomTypeBean.setRoomRank(room.getRoomrank());
                        if (room.getChildrenallowed().equals(Constants.STATUS_TRUE)) {
                            getRoomTypeBean.setChildrenAllowed(true);
                        }
                        if (room.getMultiplechildrate().equals(Constants.STATUS_TRUE)) {
                            getRoomTypeBean.setMultipleChildRate(true);
                        }
                    }
    
                    List<Bed> bedList = bedRepository.findByRoomIdOrderByBedtypeBedtypeAsc(room.getId());
                    System.out.println("####3 bedRepository.findByRoomIdOrderByBedtypeBedtypeAsc ==========" + bedList.size());
                    bedList.stream().forEach(bed -> {
                        BedtypeBean bedTypeBean = new BedtypeBean(bed.getBedtype().getId(), bed.getBedtype().getBedtype());
                        int indexoFBed = bedTypeBeanList.indexOf(bedTypeBean);
                        if (indexoFBed != -1) {
                            BedtypeBean getBedTypeBean = bedTypeBeanList.get(indexoFBed);
                            getBedTypeBean.setChecked(true);
                            getBedTypeBean.setRoomId(room.getId());
                            getBedTypeBean.setBedId(bed.getId());
                            getBedTypeBean.setAdntAdult(bed.getAdntadult());
                            getBedTypeBean.setMaxChildren(bed.getMaxchildren());
                            getBedTypeBean.setMaxOccupancy(bed.getMaxoccupancy());
                            getBedTypeBean.setStdAdults(bed.getStdadults());
                        }
    
                        List<Rateplan> ratePlanList = ratePlanRepository.findByBedId(bed.getId());
                        System.out.println("####33 ratePlanRepository.findByBedId ==========" + ratePlanList.size());
                        ratePlanList.stream().forEach(ratePlan -> {
                            MealPlanBean mealPlanBean = new MealPlanBean(ratePlan.getMealplan().getId(),
                                    ratePlan.getMealplan().getMealplanplan(), ratePlan.getMealplan().getMealplancode());
                            int indexOFMealPlan = mealPlanBeanList.indexOf(mealPlanBean);
                            if (indexOFMealPlan != -1) {
                                MealPlanBean getMeanPlanBean = mealPlanBeanList.get(indexOFMealPlan);
                                getMeanPlanBean.setChecked(true);
                                getMeanPlanBean.setBedId(bed.getId());
                            }
                            bedTypeBean.getMealplanBeanList().add(mealPlanBean);
                        });
                        mealPlanBeanList.stream().forEach(meanPlan -> {
                            if (!bedTypeBean.getMealplanBeanList().contains(meanPlan)) {
                                bedTypeBean.getMealplanBeanList().add(meanPlan);
                            }
                        });
                        roomTypeBean.getBedtypeBeanList().add(bedTypeBean);
                    });
    
                });
                contractTabBean.setSelectedroomTypeBeanList(this.loadRoomcombinationWithItsRealatedBedInfoAndRatePlan(hotelId));
                System.out.println("ContractTabBean loadRoomCombinationInfo process end :::::::::: ");
                return contractTabBean;
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("ContractTabBean loadRoomCombinationInfoException :::::::::: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return contractTabBean;
        }
```

I have used `@Transactional` and `@Service` annotations above the class of this method.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle. Refactor the method to concentrate solely on loading room combination information. Steer clear of updating or creating data within this method, as it should strictly handle the designated feature. Currently, identifying the described problem is challenging, even with the ability to debug the code.